# how to call all methods and functions from view controller to app delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, location, nstimer

Hi am developing a app using swift2 in my app i want to track location for every 5 minutes when user successfully logged in now i can successfully track location of the user now i want to track when the app is in backgrounded for that i have to use app delegate but all functions and methods are i wrote in view controllers only so how can i call view controllers method and function to app delegate.

code in *viewController*:

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController{

In view did load:

 {

  //////   i created timer scheduled with time internal  /////

 }

 //////   Here am fetched current locations and performed some function for timer to execute   //////

 }
```

In my *appDelegate*:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

 if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != .Active{

 //here i have to call that timer function execute how to do that????

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire notification when app goes to background

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

 if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != .Active{

  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Notificationname", object: nil)
}
}
```

in your controller view did load dd observer for notification

```
// add observer for notification.
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.notificationReceived), name: "Notificationname", object: nil)
```

Method handler for received Notification

```
func notificationReceived() {
// do what you want to do here.
}
```

Comment: i have not used anything like notification....how to use that??what is "notificationname " you provided in your coding.can you explain a bit...sorry @sahil

Comment: read it from here https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/

Comment: you can also do in other way. but that approach is not good. 

let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
if let activeController = navigationController!.visibleViewController {
    if activeController.isKindOfClass( YourControllerClass )  {
  // call YourControllerClass method
   }
}

Comment: in oneview controller i have implemented all methods and functions for mapview..then i used nstimer for updating location for every 3 minutes..now that location should be update even app in backgrounded..i hope you know the methods and functions for working and displaying mapview...so that has many functions and methods..which i have to call in appdelegate with executing nstimer????understood???

Comment: Yes! I got it. You can simply fire the notification wherever in Appdelegate just like i did. And in notification handler simply call the method.

Comment: just help me what functions and methods should i want to implement in appdelegate....@sahil

Comment: what issues you're facing?

Comment: i cant able to implement that function and method in appdelegate

Comment: which method? you just have to write NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Notificationname", object: nil) in applicationDidEnterBackground.

Comment: notificationReceived this method you have to write in your controller class. and NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.notificationReceived), name: "Notificationname", object: nil) add this to viewDidLoad method.

Comment: i will check that sahil...thank for your response...here server problem so i cant able to reply soon sorry

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create a class with your function inside it and then call it from your app delegate, you can do this like this:

- Create a swift file with the name of your class e.g. `MyClass.swift`
- Then you create the class in your file and add the function in it:

`class MyClassName {
       Add your function in here
  }`

- Then you call it from `appDelegate.swift` like this:

  `let myClassVar: MyClassName?`
- Then call the function like this -> `myClassVar.functionName`

Comment: i have already created swift file and performed some other functions for internet connectivity...is there possible to add coding to same file

Comment: Yes if you want you could create a class within that file outside you View controller class right under it. However it is not a good practice to do so but it will fix the issue you are having.

Comment: is there any alternative method

Comment: Yeah the method I displayed in my answer. Using this method you will be able to put all your functions inside the class and call it from anywhere. This will lead to your code being more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != .Active{
      let thirdViewController = ThirdViewController()
      thirdViewController.functionYouWantToCall()
 }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: i will try this one

Comment: What is the issue again?

Comment: it not calling that function

Comment: i want to call all the method and functions to app delegate..because its for updating location..so i need to call latitude and longitude

Comment: Have you tried notifications @antonyraja. and this won't work because let thirdViewController = ThirdViewController() it is creating new instance  of ThirdViewController everytime.

Comment: i dont know to work with notification...can you provide any examples for that  with updating location in background@sahil